# Getting error after upgrading to rails 3.1.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have just upgraded from rails 3.1.11 to 3.1.12. I am using ruby 1.9.3. After I start up server using **rails s**, I get below error

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Uncaught exception: No such middleware to insert after: "ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions"
```

My Gem file is below

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.12'
gem 'rake'
gem 'rack'
gem "haml"
gem "haml-rails"
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
```

The issue is with newrelic_rpm and airbrake gems. If both are removed the application works. 
With newrelic_rpm we get this error.

```
Uncaught exception: undefined local variable or method `establish_connection' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
```

With airbrake we get this error

```
Uncaught exception: No such middleware to insert after: "ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions"
```

Comment: Make sure your Airbrake gem is up to date: http://help.airbrake.io/discussions/problems/710-no-such-middleware-to-insert-after-actiondispatchshowexceptions

Comment: my airbrake gem is up to date that 3.1.11, but this does not solve my problem.Thanks

Comment: Question has been updated